# How can you say you realize something from someone's look?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, expressions

What is a word or phrase that means you understand something from someone's look, e.g. you realize from their look that you should stop talking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the word 'apparent' handles this well, unless you mean specifically "apparent from one's body language and mannerisms". In which case I can't think of a word.

Answer (score 1):

I like [*evident*](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/evident) (especially since it involves *seeing*):

> easy to see or understand; readily apparent. (TFD)

It is from Latin *ēvidēns*, to see from.

Answer (score -1):

"Perceive" is a transitive you could use.